# Reorder Element value after Array Index change

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
var array = [];
$('input').click(function(){
  var value = this.value;
  if (array.indexOf(value) > -1) {
    array.splice(array.indexOf(value));
    $(this).next('span').html('');
    return false;
  }
  array.push(value);
  $(this).next('span').html(array.indexOf(value));
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <input type='button' value="x">
  <span></span>
</div>
<div>
  <input type='button' value="y">
  <span></span>
</div>
```

In my Script here, I insert the `index` in the next `span` after `input`, So when you click `x` you get `0` and When you click `y` you get `1` and viceversa, The problem is When I click again on `x` which has index `= 0`,

What I expect is for the `span` of `y` to change to `0` instead of `1` since the key place changed after removing `x` index,

But that doesn't happen and the span stays `1` But if clicked it again, It changes to `0`, How do I fix this problem?

EDIT: Added jQuery tag

Comment: It doesn't look like you ever tell the `span` after `y` to change it's text. You are only ever telling the spans after the clicked input to change. If you want both to update, you'll need to update both.

Comment: @TheCrzyMan Yes, That what I want to achieve but don't know how to make it dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my go at updating everything using JQuery.
[Something to note is that the `splice` function actually takes more arguments than just the index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice). If you don't supply the `length` parameter, it will delete everything in the array after the index.

```js
var array = [];

$('input').click(function(){
  var value = this.value
  var result = true;
  var i = array.indexOf(value);
  if (i > -1) {
    array.splice(i, 1);
    result = false;
  } else {
    array.push(value);
    
  }
  updateSpans();
  return result;
})

function updateSpans(){
    $("input").each( function(){
       var i = array.indexOf(this.value);
        var newHTML = i;
        if (i == -1){
        newHTML = "";
        }
        $(this).next('span').html(newHTML);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <input type='button' value="x">
  <span></span>
</div>
<div>
  <input type='button' value="y">
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should give an ID to span elements to relate the buttons value with span elements, than you should only delete the element from array and not break the function. 
Each time you click the button the content of span elements will be delete and created again, for each element that exist in array.

```js
var array = [];
$('input').click(function(){
  var value = this.value;
    if (array.indexOf(value) > -1) {
      array.splice(array.indexOf(value),1);
    }else{
      array.push(value);
    }

  $('span').html('');
  $.each(array, function(i, item){
    $('#'+item).html(array.indexOf(item));
  });

  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type='button' value="x">
<span id="x"></span>
<input type='button' value="y">
<span id="y"></span>
```

Comment: Pretty simple to be used, But the updated HTML construct doesn't apply on it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I created an outside function called 'updateDisplays' that will dynamically populate the spans as your array list changes...

```js
// Make array[] global so that it can change across all the code
var array = [];

// bind all input elements (TODO: narrow input to specific type
// and/or class name) to a click event
$('input').click(function(){
  // get the value of the input button
  var value = this.value;
  // test if the input's value already exists in the global 
  // array[]
  var i = array.indexOf(value);
  // if the element does already exist in the array[]...
  if (i > -1) {
    // remove it
    array.splice(i, 1);
  }else{
    // if it is not in the array, add it 
    array.push(value);
  }
  
  // update the display output... 
  updateDisplays(array);
})

function updateDisplays(array){
  // cycle through each button that exists on the page
  $('input[type="button"]').each( function(){
    // find if the value of the button exists in the array[]
    var index = array.indexOf( $(this).attr('value') );
    
    // ternary condition to set the value for 'output'
    // if the index is less than zero -- the value does not 
    // exist in the array; so the string value is empty
    // if the index is greater than or equal to zero --
    // the value does exist in the array, so the string value
    // is the text conversion of the index number
    var output = (index < 0 )? '' : index.toString();
    // ^not totaly nessecary to convert a number to a string
    // in JavaScript/HTML -- it's just a nice coding convention
    // to follow.
    // update the neighboring span of the button with 'output'
    $(this).next('span').html( output );
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <input type='button' value="w">
  <span></span>
</div>
<div>
  <input type='button' value="x">
  <span></span>
</div>
<div>
  <input type='button' value="y">
  <span></span>
</div>
<div>
  <input type='button' value="z">
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Not exactly, I want to update each `span` with its `input` index in the `array`, For example: `x=0, y=1`, If I clicked on `x` again, I expect the result to become `y=0` and `x` is gone.

Comment: Updated code -- let me know if I'm getting closer :)

Comment: a Little, I'm supposed to remove the `index` from the `array` when I click it again, But now it just changes its order, Same goes to the `unindexed` value at first, It gives the `span` a value of `-1`, But I want the `span` empty if its `input` value doesn't exist in the `array`.

Comment: @Toleo -1 is the value of an empty array. When an array no longer has any elements it's value is -1 and it still exists as `arr = [ ]`

Comment: Another update! :) So, here I put in some if/else logic.  If on click the element already exists in the array, just remove it. Else add the new element to the array.  Same with the output value, if the index is greater than 0 print it out, otherwise print nothing.